# Put vimeo videos in my website homepage

Tags: oauth, vimeo, vimeo-api

i need to put videos taken from a specific vimeo album. The videos are private (hide from video) so i need to use the advanced api but it seems that OAuth needs an user click to proceed. How can i show directly the videos?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are starting now I would recommend the [new API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api)

Second, if you are only ever using a single user you can just hard code your authentication into your app. Vimeo's [documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#single-user) describes this feature in more detail.